# Can a Non-Genius use a larval wonder with 0 mania activation?

Tags: genius-the-transgression

I was sifting through the rules, and there are a few wonders that does not need any mania to activate (most of the Apokalipsi and Prostasia wonders, level 3 wonders with -3 mania variable).

Also, if you use a Larva (one of the wonder's components was obtained through a transgression, bonus points if the transgression made the genius degenerate), you can reduce the bound mania by 2.

And finally, templated creatures does not suffer havoc.

My question is, does a templated creature, say a Vampire, can use a zero bounded mania, zero activation mania, such as a jacket made from the skin of an orphan that protects against the light of the sun [Prostasia 2 wonder, larval (-2 bound mania), protects against specific thing, less effective against ballistic damage] that would negate 6 dice of aggravated damage caused by sun exposition?